# Is there a way to represent logical not with && or ||

Tags: algorithm, if-statement, logical-operators

**Is there a way to represent logical not, with `&&` or `||` or some statement like `if` or `?:`**

I want to implement this in some other way:

```
boolean isRunning = true;
startButton.setEnabled(!isRunning); // <<== ???
```

Comment: Why?  This just makes no sense.

Comment: what language is this???

Comment: @Henk to satisfy myself

Comment: @Esko language doesn't matter, i wrote it just to get vision with enabling/dis button

Comment: I can't understand this downvotes, just cause it doesn't makes sense.

Comment: If you look at the truth tables of AND and OR, it's fairly easy to see why this isn't possible. There's just no way to choose an input value that would "flip" the other input.

Comment: If u post that as answer, maybe it get accepted, but not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are doing this as an exercise, ternary operator lets you replace `!` in a simple and straightforward way:

```
startButton.setEnabled(isRunning ? false : true);
```

As far as using `&&` and `||` by themselves goes, this pair of operators is not [*functionally complete*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness), i.e. there are operations that cannot be implemented by using a sequence of `&&`s and `||`s alone; not `!` operation is among operations that cannot be implemented with ands and ors.

Comment: @FlowIng You are welcome! Take a look at the link on functional completeness, especially the list of minimal functionally complete operator sets.